# Python PEP 484 Type Hints -> return type either class name or None?

Tags: python-3.6, type-hinting

I'm using Python 3.6.5.

Class A, below for me represents a database table, using SQLAlchemy.

I'm defining a `@staticmethod` method that returns a row, but if there's no result, it would return `None`.

Since it returns an instance of class A, then the notation normally goes:

`-> A:`

at the end of the `def` signature, but because A is not yet defined, as it's on class A itself, you are supposed to quote it as:

`-> 'A':`

Is the `-> 'A':` sufficient?
Or is there some sort of *OR* syntax?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Optional[A], this means that it can return A or None

To make a "or" between classes A and B, use Union[A, B]

Note that you should import Optional and Union from typing

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#using-none - Thank's. Got it. Optional is shorthand for Union[A,None] :-)